# Oculus Interaction: Two Grab Plane Transformer

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, interaction, oculus

I am trying to understand how the Two Grab Plane Transformer script is supposed to work, can anyone explain me the purpose of this script ? Does it behave a bit the same way as Two Grab Free Transformer ?

I am trying to modify an object only X and Y scale using hand tracking. So far Two Grab Free Transformer does quite the job, but I would like to have an influence only on X and Y scale as previously mentioned.

Thank you!